# How to get my VB.net form to focus above existing users windows and applications?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, focus, setfocus

I have a Visual Basic .Net form (launches after the splash screen tests database connectivity) and it is not focusing above other existing windows on launch.

How do I get it to focus above all existing windows and Windows Explorer windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Form.Topmost = true;
```

See the corresponding [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx).

> A topmost form is a form that overlaps
>   all the other (non-topmost) forms even
>   if it is not the active or foreground
>   form. Topmost forms are always
>   displayed at the highest point in the
>   z-order of the windows on the desktop.
>   You can use this property to create a
>   form that is always displayed in your
>   application, such as a Find and
>   Replace tool window.

Comment: Thankyou. I saw that there in the designer and I wasn't sure it would work.